# How to share logger instance among module in Python?

Tags: python, logging

the module of lib_xml.py :

```
import conf_store

def hello():
        print conf_store.logger
        conf_store.logger.debug('why')
        print 'where'
```

the module of conf_store.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python 

import os, subprocess, logging, time, shutil, fcntl
import lib_xml

def log():
        """
        a log handle
        """
        import logging.handlers
        global logger
        LOG_PATH = "/opt/conf_store.log"
        logger = logging.getLogger('conf_store')
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        ch = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(LOG_PATH)
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(ch)



if __name__ == "__main__":
        log()

        while(True):
                lib_xml.hello()
                logger.debug('what')
```

How to share the object of `logger` between lib_xml.py and conf_store.py ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leave that to the `logging` module.

Just import `logging`; `logging.getLogger()` with the same key will *always* return the same object; the following code added to `lib_xml` would log messages to the same logger:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('conf_store')
```

The logging configuration is global by design.

There is an advantage in just using the current module name as the logging key instead; it lets you tease out what location messages were logged from:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove global logger

return logger from log()

add one line: logger = log() after that